# Is this command safe to run from / as root

Tags: find, root, directory-structure

```
find . * -depth -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir
```

It finds and removes all empty folders (including hidden ones) recursively.

**I only tried it on my home folder and a pendrive in Linux PC and it worked but I don't know if it is safe to run from / as root**

I once nuked my OS by running some command off the internet (which I didn't understand) like that.

Comment: In case this helps answer the question: I'm running Lubuntu 14.04/10 amd64 with Linux 3.16-rc3

Comment: What if `/` is having some empty folders and later it will be used by some applications.It's not safe to run that command from `/`

Comment: The `. *` is pointless, that's not how `find` works. That means "find everything in `.` or  all files and folders (`*`)". The result is that everything is found twice. What you wanted was `find .` alone or `find . -name '*'` which is the same thing.

Comment: @terdon @Christopher Thanks it is much quicker now :D Can you explain please what does this mean at the end? `rmdir: failed to remove ‘.’: Invalid argument` and where can I find out about `{} +` (search engines ignore special characters)

Comment: Read `man find` and look for `-exec`, that will explain the `+`. The error is because @Christopher did not specify `-mindepth 1` so it is also finding your current directory (`.`) and attempting to delete it.

Comment: Unless you have an unusually lean setup, this command will screw up your system to some extent. Why on earth do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: 1) you should really add also `-type d` so you don't run thousands of "rmdir" on files...  2) may we ask you *why* you want to remove empty directories everywhere? As some already said : it could be problematic (programs needing a directory, creating it when installed, but having it deleted before they could use it could result in a crash, or unexpected behavior)

Comment: @Gilles @ OlivierDulac My annoyance from seeing unnecessary files and folders keeps growing the more I encounter them.Also for performance of hard disk and my own.

Comment: An empty directory isn't unnecessary. It's usually there for a reason. Just because it's empty when you look doesn't mean there won't be a file there later. An empty directory also has zero impact on performance. It isn't causing any harm. Never remove a file just because you don't understand why it's there.

Comment: Nothing is safe without understanding.  Unless it affects nothing.  In which case it is safe, but purposeless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `man` page for `rmdir` says:-

```
Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty.
```

If you want to remove all empty directories then it will be safe.  The question you need to ask is:-

*Do you want to remove **all** empty directories?*

Some applications need a directory even if it's empty.  For example, `journald` can be configured so that it only logs to persistent storage if `/var/log/journald` exists.  If you run your command when that directory is empty then it will be deleted.  Afterwards `journald` will not log to persistent storage as it can't find the directory.  I believe Fedora is configured this way by default.

Also, empty (unmounted) mount points could also be deleted by your command.  They should be reasonably easy to fix, but it could still catch you out.

Comment: Thanks this is *exactly* what I'm concerned about.I know that some applications use empty directories but *I'm asking just in case* someone might know to make sure that it is safe for my current setup.

Comment: @NatusVincere we can't know unless you tell us what your current setup is. As garethTheRed explained it can sometimes be dangerous. More to the point, it is almost certainly unneeded. Just leave the `/` directory alone.

Answer (score 0):

Though this command may be safe in most cases, it is a bad habit to use `*` where the command can accept options, because a filename starting with a dash (created by mistake or by a malicious person who could have exploited another bug) could be interpreted as an option. As someone said, the `*` is pointless here, but what you need to remember is that, especially when running a command as root, you need to control all the arguments. In general, avoid globbing without a prefix (for instance, instead of `*`, `./*` is often better). Also, be careful with symbolic links and spaces in filenames...

Answer (score -1):

`find` will print all files and folders in the directory tree. `xargs` runs the command supplied - `rmdir` for each element find returns.

`rmdir` will not remove folders that aren't empty, and will not remove files either - you can try it. `mkdir` a folder, `touch` a few files inside it and then run `rmdir` on the folder. `rmdir` will complain with something like this: `rmdir: failed to remove ‘test’: Directory not empty`, or `rmdir: failed to remove ‘test.txt’: Not a directory`

So yes, it should be perfectly safe. If you want to test, you can create a set of test folders using `mkdir` and `touch` and see if it does what you expect it to.

Also, for more info on `rmdir` - and nearly any command in *nix, run `man <command>`.

Comment: Thanks for the command explanation, I find it useful.I've already tried this in my home directory and flash storage media (as I wrote in the question) to find out how safe it is but I realized that some applications might require some empty directories.

Comment: `rmdir` will only ever remove empty directories, but that doesn't mean it's safe. Some empty directories need to exist.